# Building a list from tuples

Tags: scala

I'm trying to solve problem 12 taken from [here](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/)

To summarize, given a list of tuples:

`List((4, 'a), (1, 'b), (2, 'c), (2, 'a), (1, 'd), (4, 'e))`

the result should be a list containing each element in _2 repeated _1 times

The result would be `List('a, 'a, 'a, 'a, 'b, 'c, 'c, 'a, 'a, 'd, 'e, 'e, 'e, 'e)`

This is my attempt (see [code online](http://ideone.com/kRApDd))

```
object P12 extends App  {

    val ls2 = List((4, 'a), (1, 'b), (2, 'c), (2, 'a), (1, 'd), (4, 'e))

    println(ls2)
    println(decode(ls2))   

    def decode[A] (list: List[(Int,A)]): List[A] = {
        list.foldLeft(List[A]()) { (result, elem) => for ( n <- 1 to elem._1) result :+ elem._2 }
    }

}
```

I get the following error:

```
Main.scala:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: List[A]
list.foldLeft(List[A]()) { (result, elem) => for ( n <- 1 to elem._1) result :+ elem._2 }
```

how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` cycle does nothing, are you are using it in imperative way with immutable collection. On each iteration you create new collection from `result` with appended element and then just discard it. The result of your `for` is `Unit`, hence the error.

The correct functional way to perform your task is this:

```
def decode[A] (list: List[(Int,A)]): List[A] = {
  list.foldLeft(List[A]()) { case (result, (count, el)) =>
    result ::: (1 to count).map(_ => el).toList
  }
}
```

**UPD**: Also please note, that append operation on `List` takes linear time, so the whole `decode` becomes O(n<sup>2</sup>).

There is more efficient and concise way to perform your task, using `flatMap`:

```
def decode[A](list: List[(Int, A)]): List[A] =
  list.flatMap { case (count, el) => (1 to count).map(_ => el) }
```

Comment: why each iteration creates a new collection from result? I'm appending elements to result, and as I understand foldLeft works the result will be the input of the next iteration

Comment: @ps0604 Scala's `List` is single-linked immutable list, it has O(1) prepend( `a :: list` ) and O(N) append ( `list :+ a` ), as in later case whole new list is created. Useful [cheat-sheet](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html).

Comment: @ps0604 when I'm using `fold` with `List`, I usually prepend intermediate results to the  accumulator and then `reverse` result in the end.

Answer (score 3):

Use `List.fill` and a `flatMap`:

```
val l = List((4, 'a), (1, 'b), (2, 'c), (2, 'a), (1, 'd), (4, 'e))
l.flatMap { t => List.fill(t._1)(t._2) }
```

Answer (score 1):

This recursive function denotes (or *lists*) the semantics concisely in two cases,

```
def decode( xs: List[(Int,Symbol)] ): List[Symbol] = xs match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case (x :: xss) => List.fill(x._1)(x._2) ++ decode(xss) 
}
```

An empty list results in an empty list, else for the head element of a non empty list, expand it into a list of repeated elements and prepend it to the rest of the *decoded* list.